# How to populate Excel 2013 sheets in SP2013 library with data from Access database on SP2013?

Tags: excel, database, microsoft-access

I'm new to Sharepoint. I may not use the right terminology and sound like an idiot.  Please be kind. (I'm a former JEE developer. I understand the basic concepts. Just not sure how to translate them to Microsoft, or necessarily the correct terms in the MS world.) Thanks.

I want to know how to populate Excel sheets, stored in a Sharepoint library, from an Access database, also stored in the same Sharepoint site.

I greatly appreciate anyone who can provide some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have seen SharePoint do this it was custom .Net development.

SharePoint is just a container, it can record metadata *about* your documents but SharePoint can **not** change the documents inside

(Microsoft) Documents (when opened from SharePoint) can use that SharePoint Metadata.

Without using SharePoint you can link Excel to datasources, the Data tab has a whole section 'Get External Data'

SharePoint **can** be used to built applications to replace applications built in either Access or Excel.

Just be aware SharePoint is **not** a RDBMS and **not** a Spreadsheet

It all depends on the requirements, if you are new to SharePoint find a good consultant on what, and (more important) what **not** to do in/with SharePoint *most SharePoint consultants are blindsided to the latter*